# Generate a regexp from a sentence

Tags: nlp, regex

I am looking for a program (open source if possible) that can generate a [regexp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) from a sentence written in English given as input. E.g. I'm looking if the input sentence is:

- "All 3-letter words ending by .at except bat" the output should be `[^b]at`
- "Any word starting with the letter s" the output should be `s.*`

I am aware that there exist [different regular expression standards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2806693/395857) (more precisely the POSIX standard isn't always respected) and I'm okay if the regexp output is not POSIX although I would prefer it was.